# Export datagridview added columns to excel +formatting

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, datagridview

I made a datagridview for a project of mine, which is displayed as in the picture below :

[image]

The columns on the left are generated from my database, while the ones on the right are added dynamically (they depend on a certain value).

Here is the code that I use to export it :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null;
                app.Visible = true;
                worksheet = workbook.Sheets["Feuil1"];
                worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
                worksheet.Name = "Records";

                try
                {
                   
                    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Columns.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (dataGridView2.Columns[i].Visible)
                        {
                            worksheet.Cells[1, i + 1] = dataGridView2.Columns[i].HeaderText;
                        }
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (dataGridView2.Rows[i].Visible)
                        {
                            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView2.Columns.Count; j++)
                            {
                                if (dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Visible)
                                {

                                    if (dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value != null)
                                    {
                                        worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value?.ToString();
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = "";
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    //Getting the location and file name of the excel to save from user. 
                    SaveFileDialog saveDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
                    saveDialog.Filter = "Excel files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|All files (*.*)|*.*";
                    saveDialog.FilterIndex = 2;

                    if (saveDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        workbook.SaveAs(saveDialog.FileName);
                        MessageBox.Show("Export Successful", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    }
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }

                finally
                {
                    app.Quit();
                    workbook = null;
                    worksheet = null;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString()); }
        }
```

The issue with it is that I don't get the dynamically added columns. I always would like to know how I could export the color of cells as well. Can anyone please help me? Thank you for your time !